# Access ProgramFilesFolder from Visual Studio post-build events

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

When building a C# project in Visual Studio, in the post-build events I need to call a program that is situated in C:\Program Files\\MyProgram.exe. How can I access the "C:\Program Files" folder from the post-build events?

At this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx there are several Macros that can be used in the post-build events section of Visual Studio. Is there a Macro or is there a way to access the default ProgramFilesFolder path?

Comment: Sorry Mr. Hans, but this is not a reply to the question. Please be more constructive if you can. Do you know the macro to address the ProgramFilesFolder from the post-build section?

Comment: It is not, it is a comment.  Are you talking about %programfiles%?  Fix your question.

Comment: Question fixed to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: It works, thank you. Post it as an answer to solve the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't look for a macro, none is provided since you can also use environment variables in the pre/post-build steps.  Just like you can with a .bat file, which is the way these build steps actually execute.  You are probably looking for the %programfiles% environment variable.  So to run that program, simply use:

```
  "%programfiles%\myprogram.exe"
```

Comment: Does this get 64-bit program files or 32-bit program files?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, using %programfiles% leads to the x86 program files folder. There's an environment variable for x86 program files folder (%programfiles(x86)%) but none for the x64 folder. Thus, you can't target the x64 program files folder, neither explicitly nor implicitly, when using standard environment variables. You'll always target the x86 folder. (vs2019 professional 16.10.1)